# Get class of selected radio in a button group

Tags: jquery

How to hide a div if the selected radio of a radio button group has a class other than "red"?

```
<form>
  <input class="blue" name="model" value="XTC_01" type="radio">
  <input class="red"  name="model" value="XTC_02" type="radio">
  <input class="red"  name="model" value="XTC_03" type="radio">
  <input class="blue" name="model" value="XTC_04" type="radio">
</form>

<div id="red_info">Hidden if selected radio class is not "red".</div>
```

Thanks for Your advice.

Comment: Have you tried anything? You figured that javascript (jQuery, perhaps not necessary) is the way to go...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a lot of pseudoselectors, assuming that your code is that small

```
$('input:radio').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('red')){
        $('#red_info').show();
    } else {
        $('#red_info').hide();
    }
});
```

KISS is what you should go for!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('input:radio[name="model"]').change(function() {
    $('#red_info').toggle(this.className == 'red');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

check sample on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vijaypatel/ZwmdJ/

```
var className =  $('input[name="model"]:checked').attr('class');
```

Now check whether `className` is red or not and process further.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$('input[name="model"]').change(function() {
    var val = $("input[type='radio']:checked").attr('class');
    if(val == "red") {
       $("#red_info").hide();
    } else {
        $("#red_info").show();
    }
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eVpQn/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can simple hide the div for the checked radio button which has class Red by using the below method.

```
$("input[type='radio'][class='red']:checked").hide('#red_info')
```

Comment: Instead of using "[class='red']" you could use just ".red". It makes code more expressive :)

Answer (score -1):

```
if($("form>:not(.red)").is(":selected")){
    $("#red_info").hide();
}
```

Anyway I agree with Mario De Schaepmeester. This is so simple that jQuery is an overkill.